# Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index: range_a

Tags: php

Array Format-->

```
Array([0] => Array(
            [qus] => 1
            [y_n] => 0
            [range_a] => 0
            [desc] => 
            [range_b] => 
            [highRiskComm] => 
        ));
```

Controller -->

```
   foreach($sup_qus as $riskData){

      if($riskData['range_a']==10){
          // enter code here
      }
  }
```

Php Error:

> Severity: Notice                                       Message:  Undefined index: range_a

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

It's a multidimensional array.

```
Echo $riskData[0]['range_a'];
```

Look at the array format you posted

Array **[0]** => ...